# Xamarin.forms slider as an Audio player bar

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I would like to use slider control of xamarin.forms as an audio player bar. I have a dependency service to play the recording and get the total duration and current position. How will have to set it to my slider?

Her is my code:

```
Button btnPlay = new Button
{
    Text = "Play/Pause",
    Command = new Command(() =>
                    {
                        DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().PlayMp3File();
                    })
};
Button btnStop = new Button { Text = "Stop" };
TimeSpan timeSpan = DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().GetInfo();
Label lblDuration = new Label { Text = String.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", timeSpan) };

var slider = new Slider {
    Minimum = 0,
    Maximum = timeSpan.TotalHours,
};
var label = new Label {
    Text = "Slider value is 0",
    FontSize = 25,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
};
slider.ValueChanged += 
    (sender, e) => 
    {
        label.Text = String.Format("Slider value is {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(e.NewValue));
        DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().SeekTo(Convert.ToInt32(e.NewValue));

    };
MainPage = new ContentPage
{
    Content = new StackLayout {
        Children = {
            btnPlay,
            btnStop,
            slider,
            lblDuration,
            label
        }
    },  
    Padding = new Thickness (10, Device.OnPlatform (20, 0, 0), 10, 5)
};
```

I am setting total duration in a label. How will I have to program on change slider to set label to **current position**. And how will my **slider value** will be incremented based on file played?

*Edit*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AudioTest
{
    public interface IAudio
    {
        Task PlayMp3File();
       // bool PlayWavFile(string fileName);

        Task SeekTo(int msec);
        TimeSpan GetInfo();

        void Stop();
        double CurrentPosition();

        bool Isplaying();
    }
}
```

Audioservice.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using AudioTest.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Android.Media;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AudioService))]

namespace AudioTest.Droid
{

    public class AudioService : IAudio
    {
        public AudioService() { }

        MediaPlayer player = null;

        public async Task StartPlayerAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                if (player == null)
                {
                    player = new MediaPlayer();
                    player = MediaPlayer.Create(global::Android.App.Application.Context, Resource.Raw.test);
                    player.Start();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (player.IsPlaying == true)
                    {
                        player.Pause();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        player.Start();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        public void StopPlayer()
        {
            if ((player != null))
            {
                if (player.IsPlaying)
                {
                    player.Stop();
                }
                player.Release();
                player = null;
            }
        }

        public async Task PlayMp3File()
        {
            await StartPlayerAsync();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            this.StopPlayer();
        }

        public async Task SeekTo( int s)
        {
            await seekTo(s);
        }

        public double CurrentPosition()
        {
            if ((player != null))
            {
                return player.CurrentPosition;
            }
            else
            { return 0; }
        }

        private async Task seekTo(int mseconds)
        {
            if (player == null)
            {
                player = new MediaPlayer();
                player = MediaPlayer.Create(global::Android.App.Application.Context, Resource.Raw.test);

            }

            player.SeekTo(mseconds);
            player.Start();
        }



        public TimeSpan GetInfo()
        {
            int arr;
            if (player == null)
            {
                player = new MediaPlayer();
                player = MediaPlayer.Create(global::Android.App.Application.Context, Resource.Raw.test);

            }
            arr = player.Duration;

            return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(arr);
        }


       public bool Isplaying()
        {
            if (player == null)
            {
                return false;


            }
            else { 
            return player.IsPlaying;
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before I answer the question, let me ask you one of my own: do you really want the slider to track hours? I would expect a media slider to track seconds or tenths of seconds; hours is a very coarse step.

Assuming that you are the author of the `IAudio` interface and its implementation, my recommendation would be for the `IAudio` interface to expose and fire an event (for example: `PositionChanged`) that includes the current position whenever the playback position changes. The implementation of the `IAudio` interface is beyond the scope of this question, but I would expect that you'd subscribe to an event or register a callback with whatever media stack you're using, and that would in turn fire the `PositionChanged` event.

NOTE: I'm also assuming you really meant seconds; if you really DID mean hours, change the below position to Hours.

```
public class PositionChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public PositionChangedEventArgs(int seconds)
    {
        Seconds = seconds;
    }

    public int Seconds { get; set; }
}

public interface IAudio
{
    ...
    event EventHandler<PositionChangedEventArgs> PositionChanged;
}
```

Then, in the event handler for PositionChanged, you would update the position of the slider:

```
// note that we're caching our reference to IAudio;
// I don't know whether it's a singleton or not
var audioService = DependencyService.Get<IAudio>(); 
TimeSpan timeSpan = audioService.GetInfo();
Label lblDuration = new Label { Text = String.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", timeSpan) };

var slider = new Slider {
    Minimum = 0,
    Maximum = timeSpan.TotalSeconds,
};
audioService.PositionChanged += (s, e) => {
    slider.Value = e.Position;
    label.Text = String.Format("Slider value is {0}", e.Position);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I would like slider to track second. :-(

Comment: I have edited my question to added interface class structure

Comment: I cannot add event PositionChanged on interface, getting `Error 4 Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct`

Comment: If you're getting that error, something's syntactically wrong. Are you adding that event declaration to the body of the interface definition? And by the way, make sure you don't include my ellipse (...) - I just put it there to indicate that there were other members!

Comment: I have added that to IAudio Interface class. The error is fixed now after adding `class` to `public class PositionChangedEventArgs : EventArgs`

Comment: Getting new error: `Error 5 'AudioTest.Droid.AudioService' does not implement interface member 'AudioTest.IAudio.PositionChanged'`

Comment: Sorry about that; I had left the 'class' keyword out of my sample code. That last error is just complaining about the fact that we have declared a new event on the interface but haven't yet implemented it on the AudioService class. Look into how an event is implemented: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak9w5846.aspx

Comment: What would I have to do in the implementation of the event? Can you please help me with this..

Comment: Take a look at the link I placed in the above comment; it walks you though implementing an event.

Comment: Thanks for the reference link, but I would like to know hat logic i would have put it there in order to get your code working for me

Comment: My original answer included the logic you'd place in the PositionChanged event handler; the link above walks you through the process of exposing/firing the PositionChanged event.